# How to create function that get age from ic (identification card) by using sql

Tags: sql

a.Function *functionName*____ to get age
-- get age from attribute IC

I already created table PEMAIN. So now i wanna get each PEMAIN's age based on their ic number.

Comment: You ate going to have to provide a lot more information than this! Table structures, sample data, logic for calculating age, etc etc

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored functions are highly product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear at all what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you i need more data. Do you have the birthdate? try to convert it to timestamp and reduce the current timestamp. The answer you should divide by 31556926 the number of seconds in a year.

```
var age = (timestampCurrent - timestampBirth)/31556926 ;
```